# SQL Server 2019 pod K8S in CrashLoopBackOff. Could not open file .../master.mdf and Access is denied. Any ideas why?

Tags: sql-server

My pod for SQL Server 2019 is in a CrashLoopBackOff, and I cannot find the reason why.

The main error messages are

> Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1. FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>
> Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101. Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

Rebuild/Reroll/Reinstall/Reapply did not help in my case. It must be something on the surface. Please advice

my mssql-depl.yaml

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: mssql-depl
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: mssql
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: mssql
>     spec:
>       containers:
>         - name: mssql
>           image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
>           ports:
>             - containerPort: 1433
>           env:
>           - name: MSSQL_PID
>             value: "Express"
>           - name: ACCEPT_EULA
>             value: "Y"
>           - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
>             valueFrom:
>               secretKeyRef:
>                 name: mssql
>                 key: SA_PASSWORD
>           volumeMounts:
>           - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
>             name: mssqldb
>       volumes:
>       - name: mssqldb
>         persistentVolumeClaim:
>           claimName: mssql-claim
> ---
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: mssql-clusterip-srv
> spec:
>   type: ClusterIP
>   selector:
>     app: mssql
>   ports:
>   - name: mssql
>     protocol: TCP
>     port: 1433
>     targetPort: 1433
> ---
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: mssql-loadbalancer
> spec:
>   type: LoadBalancer
>   selector:
>     app: mssql
>   ports:
>   - protocol: TCP
>     port: 1433
>     targetPort: 1433
> ```

log from the pod

> ```
> SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
> This container is running as user mssql.
> Your master database file is owned by root.
> To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.08 Server      The licensing PID was successfully processed. The new edition is [Express Edition].
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.69 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.mdf'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.72 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.ldf'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.75 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_msdbdata.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_msdbdata.mdf'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.79 Server      Setup step is FORCE copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_msdblog.ldf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_msdblog.ldf'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.90 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14) (KB5007182) - 15.0.4188.2 (X64) 
>
>   Nov  3 2021 19:19:51 
>
>   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
>
>   Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) <X64>
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.91 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.91 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.91 Server      All rights reserved.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.91 Server      Server process ID is 360.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.92 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.92 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
>
>    -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
>
>    -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
>
>    -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.93 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 8 total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.94 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.95 Server      Detected 3095 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.95 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:58.96 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:59.00 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:59.00 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 524288 bytes for 263827 hashPages.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:43:59.31 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.21 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.30 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.35 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.36 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0 Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.40 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.44 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.50 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.51 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> ForceFlush is enabled for this instance. 
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.64 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 2. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.92 Server      clflushopt is selected for pmem flush operation.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:00.93 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.04 spid9s      [1]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.05 spid9s      Starting up database 'master'.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.11 spid9s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.11 spid9s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.13 spid9s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.13 spid9s      Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.24 spid9s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.24 spid9s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf for file number 2.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.26 spid9s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>
> 2022-01-22 18:44:01.26 spid9s      Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in sa login and enabling SQL Server Authentification. If sa login in SSMS works, it will work in pod.

this helped
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/